# Improving the efficiency of code by replacing for loop with pandas operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still learning to use numpy and pandas

I've the following dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'arrival_time':[1,1,1,3,3,5,2,4,6,2],'id_col':[4,10,5,1,7,8,2,3,6,9],'col1':[1,7,4,6,8,6,89,9,10,30],'col2':['a','r','d','t','d','k','e','a','r','d']})
```

- arrival_time : Time at which the item is arriving (More than one item can arrive at the same time)
- id_col :unique id for an item. id assignment isn't related to arrival_time.
- col1,col2 : Other columns in the dataframe

df :

```
{1:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
0             1       4     1    a
1             1      10     7    r
2             1       5     4    d, 
2:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
6             2       2    89    e
9             2       9    30    d, 
3:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
3             3       1     6    t
4             3       7     8    d, 
4:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
7             4       3     9    a, 
5:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
5             5       8     6    k, 
6:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
8             6       6    10    r}
```

Now I'm using this code to get arrival_time_df i.e., df rows having same arrival_time

```
time_unique = df.arrival_time.unique()
arrival_dict = dict()
for t in time_unique :
    arrival_dict[t] = df[df.arrival_time == t]
```

Is it possible to improve this using pandas .apply() or .map() functions.

The expected dictionary looks like this :

```
{1:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
 0             1       1     1    a
 1             1       2     7    r
 2             1       3     4    d,
 3:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
 3             3       4     6    t
 4             3       5     8    d,
 5:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
 5             5       6     6    k,
 2:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
 6             2       7    89    e
 9             2      10    30    d,
 4:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
 7             4       8     9    a,
 6:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
 8             6       9    10    r}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure about efficiency but you can try `arrival_dict_new =  dict(iter(df.groupby(df['arrival_time'],sort=False)))` , also your way is better than `apply`

Comment: Thanks. My dataframe has 174k rows and this significantly improved the runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned by @anky in comments:

```
dict(iter(df.groupby(df['arrival_time'])))
```

output:

```
{1:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
0             1       4     1    a
1             1      10     7    r
2             1       5     4    d, 
2:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
6             2       2    89    e
9             2       9    30    d, 
3:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
3             3       1     6    t
4             3       7     8    d, 
4:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
7             4       3     9    a, 
5:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
5             5       8     6    k, 
6:    arrival_time  id_col  col1 col2
8             6       6    10    r}
```

---

**Comparison** with `benchit`:

```
def m1(df):
  time_unique = df.arrival_time.unique()
  arrival_dict = dict()
  for t in time_unique :
    arrival_dict[t] = df[df.arrival_time == t]
  return arrival_dict

def m2(df):
  return dict(iter(df.groupby(df['arrival_time'])))

in_ = [pd.concat([df]*n) for n in [1,10,100,1000]]
```

seems like pandas solution is faster.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this significantly improved the time to run

Comment: thanks for the timings :-) Good to know..!! *upvoted already*